# Maxlength of HTML input with UTF8 supplementary characters

Tags: html, utf-8, html-input, maxlength

I would like to enable my users an option to enter EMoji characters in an input field. I assume that in 2019 this should be as trivial as setting the meta charset of the website to UTF-8. However when tested in Chrome or Firefox the below example counts supplementary UTF-8 characters (with length 4 bytes) differently.
In the first input I can only enter 2 more characters after the poop. In the second input I can still enter 3 more characters after `‰` which is 3 bytes long.

What is causing this inconsistent behaviour? Is there another HTML meta setting for 4 byte characters? It worked fine in Edge 17. Even trash IE 11 counts the length correctly.

```html
<input type="text" value="" maxlength="4" />
<input type="text" value="‰" maxlength="4" />
```

My Test cases:
http://jsfiddle.net/L726ryea/7/

Comment: https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/1467

Comment: Yeah it gets even worse with Flags. Try to paste ``, only one is possible due to the fact that this is double dual code point character. [Why Do Flag Emoji Count As Two Characters?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTzp76JXsoY)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [HTML5 spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#maximum-allowed-value-length) says that `maxlength` applies to the [JavaScript string length](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#javascript-string-length) which is the number of UTF-16 code units. So codepoints beyond 0xFFFF like Emojis count as two code units. This explains the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear, but you are right, this is what the current spec says.

Comment: I think it *does* answer the question precisely: The emojis are represented as a [surrogate pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) of UTF-16 code units, and the length in javascript is counted in UTF-16 code units, so this is why they count as 2 for the maxLength.

Comment: [Related spec issue](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/1467).